# Numbering of objects based on several fields in ArcGIS with ArcPy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, sorting, numbering

I have a feature layer. I need to number objects within the numbering of houses on each street. The first field is the city code, the second field is the street code, the third - house number. A little confused how can I number this. The picture shows how the final "VOPROS2" field should appear.

[image]

[image]

```
import arcpy
numarr=[]
curs=arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Lot",["SOATO","Address3","adr2","OBJECTID"])
for row in curs:
    numarr.append(row)
numarr.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]))
```

Comment: Which arcgis version do you have?

Comment: @BERA, arcgis 10.2.2

Comment: @BERA , yes, I've never used it. Can I do something like this without pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [collections.defaultdist(list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples)) to group by the first two fields, they will be keys in a dictionary. The value for each key will be a list of lists of all `[adr2, objectid]` belonging to that `Soato` and `Adress3`. For example:

```
d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {(1, 26): [[(5, 3)], [(3, 4)]], (2, 216): [[(4, 1)], [(12, 2)]], (3, 114): [[(1, 5)]], (3, 8): [[(4, 6)], [(3, 7)]]})
```

Then iterate over it, sort list of list by first element, number using enumerate and create a new Dictionary with objectid as key and enumerate number as value:
`d2`
`{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 1}`

```
import arcpy
from collections import defaultdict

fc = r'C:\somefolder\Default.gdb\Lots_GR'
fields = ['SOATO', 'Address3', 'adr2','OID@']

d = defaultdict(list)

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        d[row[:2]].append([row[2:]])

d2 = {}
for key, values in d.items(): #or d.iteritems()
    newvals = sorted(values, key=lambda x: x[0])
    for e, val in enumerate(newvals,1):
        d2[val[0][1]] = e

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,['OID@','VOPROS2']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = d2[row[0]]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

Comment: It worked great. There was one mistake _Objects in this class cannot be updated outside an edit session_, but it easily resolved with `with arcpy.da.Editor(workspace) as edit:`